# My group by doesn't appear to be working in disk frames

Tags: r, data.table, disk.frame

I ran a group by on a large dataset (>20GB) and it doesn't appear to be working quite right

This is my code

```
mydf[, .(value = n_distinct(list_of_id, na.rm = T)),
                      by = .(week),
                      keep = c("list_of_id", "week")
                      ]
```

It returned this error

> Warning messages: 1: In serialize(data, node$con) :
> 'package:MLmetrics' may not be available when loading 2: In
> serialize(data, node$con) :   'package:MLmetrics' may not be available
> when loading 3: In serialize(data, node$con) :   'package:MLmetrics'
> may not be available when loading 4: In serialize(data, node$con) :
> 'package:MLmetrics' may not be available when loading 5: In
> serialize(data, node$con) :   'package:MLmetrics' may not be available
> when loading 6: In serialize(data, node$con) :   'package:MLmetrics'
> may not be available when loading 7: In serialize(data, node$con) :
> 'package:MLmetrics' may not be available when loading 8: In
> serialize(data, node$con) :   'package:MLmetrics' may not be available
> when loading

I had initially loaded the library but then I ran remove.packages(MLmetrics) before running this code. Additionally, I checked conflicted::conflict_scout and there aren't any conflicts that show up with the package MLmetrics.

When I run this code

```
> mydf %>% 
+   filter(week == "2012-01-02")
```

It gives me this output

```
         week    value 
1: 2012-01-02      483     
2: 2012-01-02     61233
```

I'm concerned that something went wrong when it was grouping the data since it didn't create distinct groups of the value week. Both columns are stored as data types character.

Comment: What is `disk.frame`?

Comment: @sindri_baldur, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63775771/13513328

Comment: please provide sample data, doesn't have to be 20GB, just few rows having 2+ groups so we can run the same query as you are trying to run.

Comment: when debugging an issue, try to reduce number of dependencies in your code to ensure that issue is not caused by packages interfering to each other. So rather than using conflicted pkg you can just use `::` operator. Maybe the package you removed was needed during the runtime of your disk.frame query?

Comment: VTC: "Needs debugging details
The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem."

Comment: @Henrik, see answers below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of {disk.frame} here.

The issue is that currently, {disk.frame} doesn't the group by `within` each chunk. It does not do group-by globally like how dplyr syntax would do.

So you have to summarise it again to achieve what you want. So I suggest sticking with the dplyr syntax for now.

As @Waldi pointed out, `{disk.frame}`'s dplyr syntax works fine, and currently support for data.table is lacking so you can only achieve what you want with dplyr syntax for now.

{disk.frame} needs to implement https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame/issues/239 before it will work for data.table.

Please DM me if anyone/organization would like to fund the development of this feature.

Comment: Would it work with data.table syntax if I do a group by and then do the same group by on the output? I'm concerned that `dplyr` syntax might be slower

Comment: dplyr might be slower but not by much as the group by is likey to be dominated by disk operations! So it doesn't bother me at this stage.

Answer (score 4):

`disk.frame` looks interesting to fill a gap between RAM processing and Big Data.

To test it, I created a collection of 200 * 200 Mb CSV files for a total of 40Gb, above the 32Gb RAM installed on my computer:

```
library(furrr)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(disk.frame)
plan(multisession,workers = 11)
nbrOfWorkers()
#[1] 11

filelength <- 1e7

# Create 200 files * 200Mb
sizelist <- 1:200 %>% future_map(~{
  mydf <- data.table(week = sample(1:52,filelength,replace=T),
                     list_of_id=sample(1:filelength,filelength,replace=T))
  filename <- paste0('data/test',.x,'.csv')
  data.table::fwrite(mydf, filename)
  ##write.csv(mydf,file=filename)
  file.size(filename)
})

sum(unlist(sizelist))
# [1] 43209467799
```

As `distinct_n` is a `dplyr` verb, I first stayed in `dplyr` syntax:

```
setup_disk.frame()
#The number of workers available for disk.frame is 6
options(future.globals.maxSize = Inf)

mydf = csv_to_disk.frame(file.path('data',list.files('data')))
"
csv_to_disk.frame: Reading multiple input files.
Please use `colClasses = `  to set column types to minimize the chance of a failed read
=================================================

 ----------------------------------------------------- 
-- Converting CSVs to disk.frame -- Stage 1 of 2:

Converting 200 CSVs to 60 disk.frames each consisting of 60 chunks

 Progress: ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 100%

-- Converting CSVs to disk.frame -- Stage 1 or 2 took: 00:01:44 elapsed (0.130s cpu)
 ----------------------------------------------------- 
 
 ----------------------------------------------------- 
-- Converting CSVs to disk.frame -- Stage 2 of 2:

Row-binding the 60 disk.frames together to form one large disk.frame:
Creating the disk.frame at c:\TempWin\RtmpkNkY9H\file398469c42f1b.df

Appending disk.frames: 
 Progress: ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 100%

Stage 2 of 2 took: 59.9s elapsed (0.370s cpu)
 ----------------------------------------------------- 
Stage 1 & 2 in total took: 00:02:44 elapsed (0.500s cpu)"


result <- mydf %>% 
  group_by(week) %>% 
  summarize(value = n_distinct(list_of_id)) %>% 
  collect  

result
# A tibble: 52 x 2
    week   value
   <int>   <int>
 1     1 9786175
 2     2 9786479
 3     3 9786222
 4     4 9785997
 5     5 9785833
 6     6 9786013
 7     7 9786586
 8     8 9786029
 9     9 9785674
10    10 9786314
# ... with 42 more rows
```

So it works!
Total RAM memory used for this specific task fluctuated between 1 and 5Gb, took a bit less than 10 minutes for 2 billion rows on 6 processors, the limiting factor being seemingly disk access speed and not processor performance.

I also tested with `data.table` syntax, as `disk.frame` accepts both, but I got back way too fast 60 times more rows (as if the 60 disk.frames created out of the 200 CSVs weren't merged and/or fully processed), and a lot of `Warning messages: 1: In serialize(data, node$con)`.

I submitted an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame/issues/310).
Until this is clarified, I suggest to stay with `dplyr` syntax which works.

This example convinced me that `disk.frame` allows to process data bigger than RAM for [supported verbs](https://diskframe.com/reference/dplyr_verbs.html)