# R generate partially data.table save it to file and partially load

Tags: r, data.table, ram

Is it possible to partially generate data.tabel bigger than RAM and partially save it to the hard drive? Then in code subsequently load parts of the file to RAM, and do calculations on those parts.

Thanks

Comment: You could have a look at [disk.frame](https://diskframe.com/index.html) which allows [data.table syntax](https://diskframe.com/articles/data-table-syntax.html)

Comment: An example : https://stackoverflow.com/q/63851782/13513328, not sure [issue with data.table](https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame/issues/239) is resolved

Comment: None of `data.frame`, `data.table`, nor `tbl_df` are capable of dealing with objects that are larger than RAM supports. `dbplyr` provides `tibble`-like functionality that allows you to work with data in a database, which could easily be larger-than-RAM as a whole, so that's possible. `disk.frame` works as partial-in-memory and can support (among other things) `data.table`-like syntax, if that's your preference. Alternatively, though, you may want to consider a different approach: *use a database*. With docker it's not hard to do so on a PC with modest capabilities.